# cakephp select box with recursive 2

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, drop-down-menu

I have `Tarifs`, each tarif `hasMany` `Price` and `Price` also `belongsTo` `UserGroup`. So basically prices change when user's group is changed - doesn't matter that much.

The view looks like this

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Tarif');?>
    ...
        $i=0;
        foreach ($this->data['Price'] as $price) {

            echo "<tr><td>".$this->Form->input("Price.$i.price", array('label' => false))."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$this->Form->input("Price.$i.currency", array('label' => false))."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$this->Form->input("Price.$i.UserGroup.id", array('label' => false))."</td>";
    ...
```

And I need the `UserGroup.id` input to display as a select, where each option displays group name and has its `id` as value. The user_group_id values are fine, but the are displayed in a text input. I've tried `$this->Form->select` and `$this->Form->input(...,'type'=>'select')` but both of them provided select boxes with no options. 
How do I set the input to do what I want?
Thanks

Comment: can you add pr($price); and show us one of your arrays? You are right with $this->form->input(array('type'=>'select', 'option'=>$price['UserGroup']['name'])); Note: this is a blind response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you need to add:

```
$user_groups = $this->UserGroup->find('list');
$this->set(compact('user_groups');
```

Then in the view, you setup the drop down like:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('user_group', array('options' => $user_groups)); ?>
```

You can then add $user_groups as an option to any Form->input and it will become a dropdown when using:

```
array('options' => $user_groups)
```